# Can I GROUPMEAN center one variable and not the second one involved in an interaction / Multilevel Model with L1 Moderation

Tags: interaction, multilevel-analysis, centering, mplus

I'm fitting a multilevel model with an L1 moderation on Mplus.

I am trying to demonstrate that the effect of X (independent variable / mean of scale items) on Y holds only when people do not make a lot of effort (my moderator W is effort / one item used as an observed variable).

I am wondering if it is possible to GROUPMEAN center X only and not W and use the result as my interaction term. There seems to be a ceiling effect that I cannot show when centering W (the main effect disappears for individuals with high levels of W / high levels of W override the impact of X on Y). If this is statistically wrong, then how can I unpack this ceiling effect? If it is correct, can you please direct me to papers that support such an approach?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: At what levels are X and W measured?

Comment: Hello! Both have been collected and measured at the within level

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question. In brief, the W moderator must be group-mean centered either manually or by automatically allowing Mplus to do this with latent group-mean centering. The issue is that the W variables has B-group variance, which would mean the X*W interaction would involve a cross-level interaction due to the B-level variance in your variable W.